# Webpage number of HTML nodes explodes: how to diagnose?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-vue

I couldn't yet figure out what actions lead for the number of HTML nodes to explode in a vue3 app.

Where do I start to figure the
[image: HTML nodes explode]

Unfortunately, there's no error. And after a while, the browser tab goes out of memory.

[image: browser tab out of memory]

Right now, I'm trying to inspect the element to figure out what those HTML elements before the tab blows up but not successful yet.

Are there any clues I can follow please?

Comment: Are you nesting a component inside itself by accident?

Comment: Share a bit of your code please